# For any permutation $ \sigma \in S_n$, $(σ(1) − 1)(σ(2) − 2) . . . (σ(n) − n)$ is even when $n$ is odd

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

Let σ be a permutation of ${1, 2, 3, . . . , n}$, n odd. I want to show that
$(σ(1) − 1)(σ(2) − 2) . . . (σ(n) − n)$
is even.

Thank you.

Comment: Show us your work, please. Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 3):

HINT: The product is even if and only if at least one of the factors $\sigma(k)-k$ is even, so you want to show that if $n$ is odd, it’s impossible for all of those factors to be odd. Look at their sum,

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\big(\sigma(k)-k\big)=\sum_{k=1}^n\sigma(k)-\sum_{k=1}^nk\;;$$

if you think about it right, you can evaluate it exactly without doing any real work at all. And if you have an odd number of integers adding up to that total, is it possible for all of them to be odd?

Comment: Is there a name to this $\sum_{k=1}^{n}(\sigma(k)-k)$ quantity?